# How to debug USB-C Power Delivery?

Tags: usb, usb-c

I have a laptop that supports USB-C Power Delivery, a ThinkPad T470. Charging it via a Lenovo USB-C power cable works fine, so USB-C PD works in general on this laptop.

I also have a monitor with USB-C PD on it, the 24MD4KL-B. The monitor should support up to 85W PD, and charging my phone via USB-C works fine. However, I cannot get my laptop to charge from it. I'm using the USB-C PD cable that came with the monitor. The monitor will work as a second display, so it's not a dead cable.

I have determined that the kernel thinks everything should be working:

```
$ cat /sys/class/typec/port0/usb_power_delivery_revision
2
```

```
$ cat /sys/class/typec/port0-partner/supports_usb_power_delivery
yes
```

What further steps can I take to debug why my laptop is not charging via USB-C Power Delivery from the monitor?

Comment: If your system is not charging via USB-C then it's likely that your system's hardware requires a certain amount of power to actually power via USB-C.  It's likely that your monitor is not outputting enough wattage to trigger.  Which is going to be something hardware related, not Ubuntu related, making debugging much harder.

Comment: I dont have path `/sys/class/typec` at all. Ubuntu 20.04